# register controller dynamically in directives of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to develop a single page application with angular.I need to register controllers on demand in directives. I did this in app.config where i set my URL's but i could'nt do it in directives.

I want do it with Promises and this is my own code

this is my directive code

```
app.directive('componentLoader', ['$http', '$q','loader', function ($http, $q,loader) {
//app.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;
var controllerpath;
var viewpath;
return {

    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    name: 'ctrl',
    controller: '@',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {


        //'Modules-blue'
        var urlArray = attrs.component.split('-');
        var urlpath = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
            urlpath += (i == 0 ? '' : '/') + urlArray[i];
        }

        controllerpath = urlpath + "/controllers/" + urlArray[urlArray.length - 1] + ".js";
        viewpath = urlpath + "/views/" + urlArray[urlArray.length - 1] + ".html";


        var htmlText = '';
        $http.get(viewpath)
            .then(function (response) {

                htmlText = response.data;
                element.replaceWith(htmlText);
                loader.loadcomponent(controllerpath);
            });

    },

}}]);
```

and this is loader service that i injected in the directive

```
app.service('loader', function ($q,$controller) {


function loadScript(path) {

    var result = $.Deferred(),
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = "async";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = path;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function (_, isAbort) {
        if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) {
            if (isAbort)
                result.reject();
            else
                result.resolve();
        }
    };
    script.onerror = function () { result.reject(); };
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
    return result.promise();
}

function loader(arrayName) {

    return {
        load: function ($q) {

            var deferred = $q.defer(),
            map = arrayName.map(function (name) {
                return loadScript(name);
            });

            $q.all(map).then(function (r) {
                deferred.resolve();
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
};


this.loadcomponent = function (url) {

    var urlarray = new Array();
    urlarray.push(url);

    loader(urlarray).load($q);

};});
```

this code register's script in the page but it does not run at all while this service works perfect in app.config

Comment: If I remember correctly, controllers need to be added to angular using `app.controller('myController', controllerObject)` before the angular application is bootstrapped, so you wont be able to load controller script in dynamically like that, unless you postpone the bootstrapping of angular (in which case you cannot use angular directives for the dynamic loading).

Comment: @ Nikolaj Dam Larsen thank you for your attention to my question. yes you remember correctly but with `app.registerCtrl` you can register controllers dynamically or lazy or on demand i want to do it in the directive that has duty to load controllers inside another like patials